# How to search for a string using each member of array as a parameter

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to search for a string using each member of an array

I can search for an string by a string by using .includes() but would like to send in an array of strings and search by each member

**// Currently searches for whole string**

```
let lsearchText = this.config.searchText.toLowerCase()
a.Categories.toString().toLowerCase().includes(lsearchText)
```

**// I want to search by each member of split array seperately**

```
let lsearchText = this.config.searchText.toLowerCase().split(' ');
a.Categories.toString().toLowerCase().includes(lsearchText)
```

Im getting error

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

My full function

```
get filteredAlbumListArray() {
        if (this.config.searchText && this.config.searchText.length > 1) {
            let lsearchText = this.config.searchText.toLowerCase().split(' ');
            return this.albumList.filter((a) =>



                a.Frequency.toLowerCase().includes(lsearchText)
                ||
                a.Year.toString().toLowerCase().includes(lsearchText)
                ||
                a.Title.toLowerCase().includes(lsearchText)
                ||
                a.Categories.toString().toLowerCase().includes(lsearchText)
                ||
                a.Description.toLowerCase().includes(lsearchText)
                ||
                a.FieldNames.replace(/_/g, ' ').toLowerCase().includes(lsearchText)

            );
        }
        return this.albumList;
    }
```

So if i type in Weekly 2019 id like to return results that Are both Weekly and 2019

Comment: Share it in stackbiltz or show categories array and lsearchText

Comment: @AdritaSharma working examples should be made *right here* in the question as a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try somehting like this

```
const lsearchTexts: string[] = this.config.searchText.toLowerCase().split(' ');
lsearchTexts.some(lsearchText => a.Categories.toString().includes(lsearchText));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   let result =[];
   lsearchText.forEach(l=>{
     if(a.Categories.includes(lsearchText)){
     result.push(l);
   }
   })
```

you'll find existing members in th result array

Answer (score 0):

You can split the search string and use map/filter or any other operation using it same as array. Since no example is given i'll take some random example.

```
searchFor = "some text";
searchIn = "some thing to search";

// using filter you can remove the not available substring
searchFor.split(" ").filter(st => searchIn.includes(st)) // prints - ["some"]
searchFor.split(" ").filter(st => searchIn.includes(st)) // prints - "some"
```